# circular buffer resets memory?

Tags: c++

When this cycles back around dd[0] is set to  0 as apposed to 256.1 ??  It seems like 'dd' memory is resetting with 'aa' back to 0.

```
unsigned char aa = 0;
double *dd = new double[256];

//circular buffer
dd[aa] = 0.1;
for(int i = 0; i < 600; i++){
    qstr += QString::number(aa,'d',0) + "  " + QString::number(dd[aa],'f',1) + "         ";
    aa++;//onces 'aa' reaches 255, the next increment resets back to 0 for 'aa'
    dd[aa] = dd[aa - 1] + 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know exacly, but maybe need cast in aa - 1 in last expression: dd[aa] = dd[static_cast< unsigned char >( aa - 1 )] + 1; - correct me, please, if I'm wrong but aa - 1 can be type int, not unsigned char, so you get memory access error.

Comment: You are hoping that aa-1 will overflow back to 255.  It doesn't, it is evaluated as an integer expression.  The result will be -1.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I did casting to avoid the -1 and it solved it thanks.  Gave you a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did casting to avoid the aa = -1:

```
    dd[aa] = 0.1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 600; i++){
        qstr += QString::number((unsigned char)((unsigned char)aa-(unsigned char)1),'d',0) + "  " + QString::number(dd[aa],'f',1) + "         ";
        aa++;
        dd[aa] = dd[(unsigned char)((unsigned char)aa-(unsigned char)1)] + 1;  // casting
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have `aa` declared as `unsigned char`.
So when you hit 255 and increment, it goes back to 0. You should probably be using an int since this variable is used as an array index variable.

Comment: aa is supposed to.  But dd should not:  dd[0] = dd[255] - 1 ... shouldn't it still grow?

Comment: I want aa to cycle back around but dd should still be incrementting

Comment: Well, for one thing you're indexing out of the dd array once aa wraps, since when aa = 0, you get dd[aa-1], which is dd[-1]. That means the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I didn't down vote...  but as Hans Passant said the issue is the evaluation is done as integer... so I casted it to (unsigned char) and it solved it... posted solution below.

Answer (score 2):

It is because when `aa` increments by one from `255` it goes to `0` because of `unsigned char`, So it becomes `dd[0] = dd[-1] + 1` now any `junk` can be present at `dd[-1]` and here it seems you have `-1`.

Also, you're accessing the array out of its bounds it is an undefined behavior.
You should try avoiding when `aa` becomes `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned char is 8 bit long. The maximum number that can be held by unsigned char is 255. (in binary 1111111). If you increment it by 1, it will become 0